# QGIS 2.18.15 64-bit Las Palmas won't start. Missing Qgis_app.dll; Qgis_gui.dll; Qgis_core.dll

Tags: qgis

A week ago my QGIS wouldn't start anymore. When I double click the desktop shortcut nothing happens. When I run in from the .exe in the bin I get the error that some DLL files are missing. These files are however present in the map 'apps'.

On this forum several suggestions are given. I tried booting from the qgis.bat file, but that does not work. I also tried uninstalling QGIS and deleting all temporary files to ensure a clean re-install. Also does not work. I tried installing older versions, but they all give the same error.

One thread also suggests modifying the .bat file by adding : PATH %systemroot%\system32; %systemroot%; %systemroot%\system32\wbem after @echo off. Also didn't work.

Lastly I installed the latest Microsoft Visual C ++ which also had no effect.

I use a Windows 10 pro edition 64 bit on my desktop. I'm not sure, but I think QGIS stopped working after a major update. When I went back to before the update, QGIS still wouldn't work however.

Comment: If you are currently using the stand-alone installer, you might want to try the OSGeo4W installer instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
I tried installing with the OSgeo4W installer, but the same issue still exists. 
After the installation i got the error that the 'QGIS-common' and the 'QGIS-common.bat exit code 255' where not installed.

I tried starting it using all the above described methods, but no succes.

Comment: Have you tried to install the previous version? Like 2.18.14 or 2.18.12? I encountered with this problem several times and always try to uninstall the latest version of QGIS and install with previous version (i.e. if i got error in QGIS 2.18.15, I try QGIS 2.18.14)

Comment: Yes i tried. Also didn't work. I  currently gave up and only use qgis on my laptop where it works perfect. Only thing i didn't try yet for my desktop is reinstalling windows. Seems to me like the last option.

Comment: I have the same problem too. Have you find any solution?

Comment: For me the solution *was* actually to use the qgis.bat file, on an OSGeo4W install. But something certainly changed because it used to work out-of-the-box.

Comment: For me, nothing worked. Latest Qgis desktop version does work again however.